# Screen Printing Color Seperation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, screen-printing, color-separation

I really don't understand these color separation channels for screen printing

[image][image]
Here are all Channels. You can see RGB and I dont understand what they are channels  2-305-process   ?
[image]

Comment: Hi Vincent, If you see image at first I was thinking that I have pantone colors separation but is not that and I don't understand what it is. In 2 minutes I will post one more image to see more clear

Comment: @JelenaPetrovic Your image is still broken please try to reupload it!

Comment: I reuploaded on answer and I can see images on my screen. I will reupload one more time. Thanx :)

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/108902/95475

Comment: please use the 'edit' link on your question to try and add images, please don't use the answer field!

Comment: If you don't understand where , how, or why those channels were added, where did you get the file? Just to try and gage a sense of experience, why do you need to know?

Comment: Hi Scott some client send me and he tell me he needs for future projects color separation like this :)

Comment: Okay these are **spot color channels** in Photoshop, although they aren't customarily part of an RGB file. See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18566/how-do-i-identify-text-layers-as-individual-pms-colors

Answer (score 3):

You have a CMYK separation with a white base color for dark textiles.

Every channel must be reticulated before printing or reticulated in a rip printer.

The channels you are showing are just grayscaled separeated inks, where we see the amount of ink we must use in every silkscreen.

Answer (score 2):

[image]It seems to be a separation for silkscreen, like a DCS EPS. In silkscreen, the white is another color, the base, imagine printing on a black t-shirt (the ctrl+7 channel). The other four are the process colors for the illustration. Will be interesting to see a picture with RGB channels hidden, to see the illustration colors.

This image is an old EPS DCS i have for silkscreen with three inks. If you change the color of the channel for the correspondent ink, you will see the illustration. The order of the channels must be like in the printing process, on my case lighter colors on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how they get Ctrl+7, 8, 9... channels?

Comment: it seems they duplicate CMYK channels to a RGB file and add ctrl+7 channel with the image border. Is the easy way. On my illustration i separate every part as a different layer and use posterization.

Comment: I understand your file but I don't understand why I have RGB channels and down Ctrl+7, 8, 9... channels (2-305-Process yellow). I am confused a little bit with that :)

Comment: I guess you can delete RGB channels. May be they keep them because if you delete them, after there are no possibilities for saving as JPG to send the file. They file will become a Multichannel file and EPS DSC is the format to save it, but the file gets bigger.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand better this :)